# pandas TimeSeries diff() reverts to Series

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with some TimeSeries data in this format:

> 1984-12-12 14:08:00
>   1984-12-12 14:25:00
>   1984-12-12 14:47:00
>   1984-12-12 16:37:00
>   1984-12-12 16:37:00
>   1984-12-12 16:37:00
>   1984-12-12 17:52:00
>   1984-12-12 17:52:00
>   1984-12-12 19:29:00

Over the past few `days!`, what seemed to be a few simple operations (a pleasant afternoon), has turned hackish and grim.

Here are the reqs btw:

- take the difference between certain rows in a TimeSeries
- generate the cumsum of the differences.

First, when I approach pandas and the whole `group-apply-combine` paradigm, what I like to do is

- create some group over the DataFrame
- write a function that takes a group object and returns a group object
- use a lamda apply to pass groups to the function

I believe this is standard, and the reason I like using it is implicit concatentation of groups, multiple columns, and new column insertion.  (it also removes looping over groups, makes vectorization easier) ... but i think it has trouble dealing with empty groups...

Anyhow, to get the differences of the TimeSeries, I found using `shift()` to get the time differences threw a `StopIteration` error, using `diff(1)` threw no errors.

However, the new delta column (the time difference between rows with events) turns into a Series.

```
time                   ev             delta

1984-12-12 14:08:00        1           NaT  
1984-12-12 14:25:00        1      00:17:00  
1984-12-12 14:47:00        1      00:22:00  
1984-12-12 16:37:00        0      01:50:00  
1984-12-12 16:37:00        1      01:50:00  
1984-12-12 16:37:00        0      01:50:00  
1984-12-12 17:52:00        0      01:15:00  
1984-12-12 17:52:00        1      01:15:00  
1984-12-12 19:29:00        1      01:37:00
```

Trying to convert Series to TimeSeries proved unfruitful.  An error is thrown do to a format issue (a verylongnumber+L is found not in format of hour,minute,sec), this apparently aborts the whole attempt and try catch cant get past it.

```
    try:
        pd.to_datetime(d['delta'], format='%H:%M:%S')
    except:
        pass
```

Another error that keeps popping up is `StopIteration` error from getting a sum of the times.

```
gg['cumt'] = pd.rolling_apply( gg['time'], 2, np.sum )
gg['cumt'] = pd.rolling_sum(gg['time'],2).shift(1)
gg['cumt'] = gg.apply(lambda x: pd.expanding_sum(x['time'], min_periods=2) )
```

I believe this a simple `cumsum` did not throw an error, `gg['cumt'] = gg['tavg'].cumsum()`, but the time formating issue causes the string to convert to some int and they are summed as tiny numbers.

Any help, general or specific is appreciated:

I like the simple idea of write a function and return a group.  Havent explored the `transform` function too much (dont think I could get it to work); does returning modified groups in functions remove the need for transforms/broadcasting.  Is this what is causing my `StopIteration` error?  I get the feeling that it cannot deal with some groups being empty ?

Comment: Show expected results.

Comment: As for me your column `time` is `Datetime Series` not `Time Series`, and `delta` is `Time Series`. For example you can add `df['time'] + df['delta']` and you get new date and time.

Comment: what version pandas/numpy? pls show your code in its entirety, and your expected putput

Comment: you cannot convert a timedelta to a datetime it doesn't make sense. (hence your to_datetime doesn't do anything) and raises correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pandas 0.12.0, Numpy 1.7.1, Python 2.7.5, Linux Mint

```
import pandas as pd
import StringIO

data = '''time
1984-12-12 14:08:00
1984-12-12 14:25:00
1984-12-12 14:47:00
1984-12-12 16:37:00
1984-12-12 16:37:00
1984-12-12 16:37:00
1984-12-12 17:52:00
1984-12-12 17:52:00
1984-12-12 19:29:00'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO.StringIO(data))

df['time'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['time'])

df['delta'] = df['time'].diff()

#df['delta'] = pd.TimeSeries(df['delta']) # sorry, not needed

#df['delta'][0] = 0 # to remove NaT 

# better method to remove NaT - thanks to Jeff
df['delta'] = df['delta'].fillna(0) 

df['cumsum'] = df['delta'].cumsum()

print df
```

result

```
                   time      delta     cumsum
0   1984-12-12 14:08:00   00:00:00   00:00:00
1   1984-12-12 14:25:00   00:17:00   00:17:00
2   1984-12-12 14:47:00   00:22:00   00:39:00
3   1984-12-12 16:37:00   01:50:00   02:29:00
4   1984-12-12 16:37:00   00:00:00   02:29:00
5   1984-12-12 16:37:00   00:00:00   02:29:00
6   1984-12-12 17:52:00   01:15:00   03:44:00
7   1984-12-12 17:52:00   00:00:00   03:44:00
8   1984-12-12 19:29:00   01:37:00   05:21:00
```

Comment: should should do ``df['delta'] = df['delta'].fillna(0)`` rather the chained indexing ``df['delta'][0] = 0`` (which happens to work because you don't have mixed dtypes other than datetime/timedelta)

Comment: @Jeff Thanks, I'm beginner in pandas and I learn it by answering on question :) I was looking for something like `fillna(0)` right now in Google but I didn't know what name can it have.

Comment: np. see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy for chained indexing reference.

Comment: thanks! yes it was the fillna(0).. i should have thought of that as Ive had similar errors 'u column' on groups before, that were resolved with pd.isnull... didnt know about fillna either... again thanks!

Comment: Cheers Jeff - your fillna advice has just helped... 4+ years later